# Mysql/Jsp accessing database

Tags: mysql, jsp

I was able declare my forms variable and also establish a connection to my MySQL Database, but when I ran the program it give me error `Class.forName` not found. Meanwhile, I think the syntax is correct:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

So what is the possible solution and the possible cause of such an error?

Answer (score 2):

This means that the mysql JDBC driver is not included in your classpath.

Answer (score 2):

have you put the MySQL jar to the project classpath or to the web container lib folder?